# update changed custom listview edittext values to mysql database in android

Tags: android, android-listview

```
        listview
       jArray = new JSONObject(result);
         json = jArray.getJSONArray("mainmenu");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainmenulist);
        adapter = new EditMainMenulistview(this, json);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
         EditMainMenulistview

        public class EditMainMenulistview extends BaseAdapter {
public final ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
protected static Context Context = null;
int i;
public String editnewmainmenu, menuname,edittext;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Bitmap[] bmps;
Activity activity = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname, itemcode;
public String[] itemnames, itemcodes;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public EditMainMenulistview(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    Context = context;
    // inflater =
    // (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemcodes = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

        for (i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("menuimage");
            itemname = image.getString("menuname");
            itemcode = image.getString("menucode");
            itemnames[i] = itemname;
            itemcodes[i] = itemcode;

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                    true);
            bmps[i] = bmp;

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }
        System.out.println(itemnames[i]);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);
        holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
        holder.caption1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
    holder.caption.setText(itemnames[position]);
    holder.caption.setId(position);
    holder.caption1.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

    //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;

                holder.caption.setFocusable(true);

                arr.add(holder.caption.getText().toString());


        }
            }

    });  



    return convertView;
}
 }

     class ViewHolder {
EditText caption;
ImageView caption1;
    }

     class ListItem {
String caption;
 }
```

if i can change all ediitext values and send to mysql database i can replace old menunames. if i cange 2 menunames i cannot update ..please tell me.............................................................

Comment: read your question again and tell us if you can understand something.. this is 3rd time your asking the same question... please be more clear  also include what you have done so far..

Comment: sir please suggest me how to update change multiple changed editext values  to mysql database

Comment: i attached my screen shot please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) method.. get All those values and then update your database (But i don't think this is what you are looking for... but your question is not clear ) ..

here are the steps you need to follow..

get references for all thos EditTexts using [findViewByID()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) and then use getText method to get all those texts and then just update database with those values..

Instead of ArrayList use HashMap.. and make these changes in your code..

```
public class EditMainMenulistview extends BaseAdapter {
public final HashMap<String, String> arr=new HashMap<String, String>;
protected static Context Context = null;
int i;
public String editnewmainmenu, menuname,edittext;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Bitmap[] bmps;
Activity activity = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname, itemcode;
public String[] itemnames, itemcodes;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public EditMainMenulistview(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    Context = context;
    // inflater =
    // (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemcodes = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

        for (i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("menuimage");
            itemname = image.getString("menuname");
            itemcode = image.getString("menucode");
            itemnames[i] = itemname;
            itemcodes[i] = itemcode;

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                    true);
            bmps[i] = bmp;

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }
        System.out.println(itemnames[i]);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);
        holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
        holder.caption1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
    holder.caption.setText(itemnames[position]);
    holder.caption.setId(position);
    arr.add(position,itemnames[position]);
    holder.caption1.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

    //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;

                holder.caption.setFocusable(true);
                arr.remove(holder.caption.getId());
                arr.add(holder.caption.getId(),holder.caption.getText().toString());


        }
            }

    });  



    return convertView;
}
 }

     class ViewHolder {
EditText caption;
ImageView caption1;
    }

     class ListItem {
String caption;
 }
```

Comment: please see now.. are u understand my question

Comment: arr.add(position,itemnames[position]); it show error . it ask u want add type cast

Comment: ya sir it works fine.. thank u very much for my understanding